# cannot print an integer to a pdf python django

Tags: python, django, django-views, pdf-generation

As the title says, I want to print integers to a pdf, because it will be a receipt, and the data for them are on FK. But I get an error named "bad argument type for built-in operation", is there any workarounds for it? here is the view of the function:

```
def receipt(request):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(buf, pagesize=letter, bottomup=0)
    textob = c.beginText()
    textob.setTextOrigin(inch, inch)
    textob.setFont ("Helvetica", 10)
    items = ShopCart.objects.all()

    lines = []

    for item in items:
        lines.append(item.product)
        lines.append(item.size)
        lines.append(item.sugar)
        lines.append(item.ice)
        lines.append(item.addOn)
        lines.append(item.quantity)
        lines.append("")

    for line in lines:
        textob.textLine(line)

    c.drawText(textob)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    buf.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buf, as_attachment=True, filename='Receipt.pdf')
```

Also, I've tried printing the said items columns on the terminal and got their values but, noticed that whenever I try to generate the PDF it will look like this:
using print()

```
tea1
Petite
10
normal
milk
1
```

Im guessing this is the

```
for line in lines:
        textob.textLine(line)
tea1
Petite
10
```

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a string?

Comment: fortunately making it a string helped, I guess it didn't cross me before nor did I know how to do it. But thanks!